# hector_slam tf error

Tags: slam, navigation, transform, hector-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, does anybody try to run hector_slam with only laser scanner?
The type of laser scanner is URG-04LX-UG01.
I tried to run mapping_box.launch & geotiff_mapper.launch and rviz.
However, I always got the error says waitForTransform timed out...
Anyone knows how to deal with the transform problem?
Thanks a lot! I am really fresh bird with it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11433/hector_slam-tf-error/) by [bona](https://answers.ros.org/users/1158/bona/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2011-10-05

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That error message of course is not very verbose. I just changed it to be more informative, you'll just have to update your svn working copy and rebuild.

Now for the error itself, it seems there is no transformation information available between the base_frame and the laser frame. These tutorials should give you an idea on why and how to fix that:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/TF http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_slam/Tutorials/SettingUpForYourRobot

The easiest way to publish such a transform in case you don't have a URDF model is to use a static_transform publisher as described here:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf#static_transform_publisher

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2011-10-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bona](https://answers.ros.org/users/1158/bona/) on 2011-10-06**:
Thanks a lot Stefan! You did help me a lot!